# part time job and visa vocabs

Tags: translation, meaning, keigo

this was my email to my prospective employer

ご返信ありがとうございました。
今学生ビザを持っていますが、労働許可証を持っていません。
労働許可証もご所望ですか？

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします

I was wondering if I needed work permit to work too.
his reply was:

お持ちの学生ビザはアルバイト可能な条件を満たしていませんか？

今後条件を満たす予定であれば、就業時期については相談可能です。

よろしくお願いします。

I'm not sure what he's asking here. is he asking me if I have plans to apply for a work permit or I don't need it?

Answer (score 1):

He says:

Does your student visa not meet conditions that allow part-time jobs?
**If you plan to satisfy the conditions in the future**, you can consult us regarding the **time of your employment** (simply put, when you will start working for them).
よろしくお願いします。(well, I suppose you know what that means).